# how to send image through android REST Web services and save it and retrieve from mysql database

Tags: java, android, json

I am new in Android development i just wanted to know how to send image through android REST web services and save it and retrieve from MySQL database

Comment: You need Base64 java class file for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience, client send the `image-string`(encoded Image byte array) to server and save it into the database.
To show the image, client get `image-string` from server and decoded `image-string` to byte array. Try to show `image byte array`.

```
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);
}

public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
}
```

Use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

Comment: can u show me the full code for sending to webservices and storing in database also.

Comment: @Ajay, If u can convert image to `encoded string`, it is just like sending `Hello World` string to server.

Comment: How i decode and Display image after retrieving from image.?

Comment: yes.. Can u tell me what datatype used for store the image? shall i use blob or VARCHAR(MAX).?

Comment: @Ajay, How can I know you image size? That's why I cannot comment data type of database. It will be another topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode Bitmap image to Base64, so you will have an image encoded as string. You can use your REST API to send and save that string to database. Later when you want to display it, download and decode it to Bitmap again. [Here is how you can do encoding/decoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768611/encode-and-decode-bitmap-object-in-base64-string-in-android)