# how can check panorama photo android?

Tags: android, gallery

I need to show all panorama photo in Gallery android. But it extension is jpg same regular photo.

How can I check a photo in Gallery android is **Panorama** photo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to extract the [XMP Metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform)

XMP Metadata is essentically image metadata...

> ...encoded in some XML-friendly format, such as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

See this previous [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768611/encode-and-decode-bitmap-object-in-base64-string-in-android) on StackOverflow to see how to [decode](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html) Base64.

Based on the xml you can decode from the jpeg, you may be able to guess the intent-filter you'll need. In the case of a photo sphere panorama format for instance, this is [the format](https://chris.orr.me.uk/photo-sphere-formats-metadata/).

> If you want to accept Photo Sphere images in your own Android apps,
>   you can add the custom `MIME` type
>   `application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg` to the relevant `IntentFilter` in
>   your app.

However, I'm not sure what type of panorama your jpeg is in. It may help if you posted the particular jpeg with your question.

Comment: Ok. let me try this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ask the mediadatabase through a filter condition

```
Where ((height/width > 2) or (width/height >= 2))
```

something like this

```
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor query = resolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
      sqlSelectColums, '((height/width > 2) or (width/height >= 2))', 
      null, sqlSortOrder);
```